# Show New Customize Error phtml Page on Magento Error once development is completed?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, page

Before I go for live I want to show customize error page for frontend and backend So user will not to see "Magento and Processing your error request".
But the log and report folder will follow its default functionality.
give your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand your question you need to enable maintenance mode

you can follow this tutorial and enable maintenance mode

https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/maintenance-mode.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own theme for error pages. Take a look at the [`errors`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.9/errors) directory.

- make a copy of the `default` directory (`your_theme`)
- copy `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml` and replace

  ```
  <skin>default</skin>
  ```

  with

  ```
  <skin>your_theme</skin>
  ```
- modify the templates and CSS in `errors/your_theme` as you wish.